# Как исправить ошибку std::basic_ostream is protected?

Tags: c++

Хочу передать поток в функцию. При компиляции получаю следующую ошибку:

> ...\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream [Error] 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]' is protected

Минимальный [воспроизводящий пример](http://ideone.com/vM3Q1c):

```
#include <ostream>

void function (std::ostream &s) { }

int main()
{
    std::ostream s;
    function(s);
}
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Павел Покажите минимальный, готовый к компиляции пример, который демонстрирует проблему, что поток, объявленный в виде параметра как ссылка, не работает, и компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @Павел И покажите полное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: 382 7 ...\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream [Error] 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected

Comment: @Павел Я между прочим то же плохо знаю английский, но знание английского не требуется, что бы среди ответа просто увидеть строчку с готовым кодом содержащим ответ

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Согласно стандарту C++ класс `std::ostream`, который объявляется как алиас для специализации класса `std::basic_ostream<char>`

```
typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream;
```

служит в качестве базового класса для классов `std::basic_ostringstream` и `std::basic_ofstream`:

> 5 The class template specialization basic_ostream serves
>   as a base class for class templates basic_ostringstream and
>   basic_ofstream.

и имеет единственный открытый конструктор, который имеет вид

```
explicit basic_iostream(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);
```

Он не имеет конструктора по умолчанию, поэтому вы не можете создать объект этого класса следующим образом:

```
ostream s;
```

Я соглашусь с вами, что это баг компилятора, так как согласно стандарту C++ у этого класса нет конструктора по умолчанию, если только в последнее время не были пересмотрены спецификации стандарта относительно этого класса.

То есть данное сообщение об ошибке компилятора `clang` и такое сообщение компилятора `gcc`

> error: calling a protected constructor of class
>   'std::__1::basic_ostream'

некорректные.

Компилятор MS VC++ выдает более корректное сообщение об ошибке

> error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream>': no
>   appropriate default constructor available

и, по-видимому, не объявляет конструктор по умолчанию, как того  требуется в стандарте C++.

Согласно стандарту C++ (17.6.5.5 Member functions)

> 3 A call to a member function signature described in the C++ standard
>   library behaves as if the implementation declares no additional member
>   function signatures.

Как мне уже подсказали, это старый баг библиотеки `libstdc++` еще со времен `gcc 3.4`, и он не может быть исправлен  так как это нарушит ABI.

Comment: @Abyx Я с этим совершенно не согласен. Если в спецификации класса говорится, что конструктор по умолчанию отсутствует, то таковой должен отсутствовать.

Comment: @Abyx Открытые и защищенные члены класса - это его интерфейс.  Интерфейс класса описывается в стандарте. Стандарт не описывает закрытые члены классов, то есть их (классов)  реализацию.

Comment: @Abyx Рассмотрите простой пример. Вы объявляете объект класса std:;string следующим образом: std:;string s( 10 ); и ваш код компилируется вашим компилятором. Является ли это багом вашего компилятора или нет?

Comment: @Abyx В том, что нет такого конструктора, тем не менее код компилируется вашим компилятором. Как вы, вообще, в таком случае будете определять, что является багом, а что нет? И что является критерием бага?

Comment: @Abyx А вы можете показать, что это добавление задокументировано в руководстве пользователей стандартной библиотеки этих компиляторов?

Comment: @Abyx А также хотелось бы знать, если опция компилятора, которая отключает это расширение языка компилятора?

Comment: @Abyx Кстати сказать, со мной согласны и другие авторитетные специалисты: Например, "
No, it's not allowed, but libstdc++ has had it since gcc 3.4 and can't remove it 
because that would be an abi break. "

Comment: @Abyx Это ссылка из стандарта.  Авторитетный специалист - это Ville Voutilainen.

Comment: @Abyx Да, в стандарте такого текста нет. А разве кто-то говорил, что это - цитата из стандарта?

Comment: @Abyx Цитата из стандарта приведена в моем ответе.

Comment: @Abyx То, что я пропустил, совершенно не опровергает то, что я написал в своем ответе.:)

Answer (score 2):

У `ostream` нет конструктора по умолчанию, ему надо передавать буфер потока.

```
ostream s(cout.rdbuf());
```

Возможно Вам надо использовать `stringstream s;`, или `fstream`.
Либо сделайте ссылку на cout:

```
ostream& s = cout;
```

Comment: [Error] aggregate 'std::fstream s' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: так можно на любой вопрос ответить лол

Comment: @Павел, не на любой к сожалению, но для нелюбых есть SO. Английский вам все же надо подучить, хотя бы для того, чтоб переводить ошибки.